# Flutter Firebase realtime database fetching the wrong node

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I have been trying to get a particular field in realtime database. The result is not the one I expected.

Version used Flutter - 3.0.0 firebase_core: ^1.17.0 firebase_database: ^9.0.14

This is the database

```
{
  "patients_today": {
    "VN76Y0TNM": {
      "MMS07K5CCLT": {
        "doctor": "Dr. John M A",
        "doctor_id": "MMS07K5CCLT",
        "patients": {
          "MMXZV5F8A": {
            "appointment_end": 1652709621742,
            "appointment_start": 1652705121742,
            "arrived_at": 1652705098791,
            "dob": 712866600000,
            "gender": "male",
            "id": "MMXZV5F8A",
            "mail": "min@min.c",
            "mobile": "+919400490000",
            "name": "Minhaz MA",
            "status": "WAITING"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
var ref = await FirebaseDatabase.instanceFor(app:Firebase.app()).ref()
     .child("patients_today")
     .child("VN76Y0TNM")//clinicId
     .child("MMS07K5CCLT")//doctorId
     .child("patients")
     .child("MMXZV5F8A")//patientId
     .get();

var data = ref.value;
```

The above code is returning the following

```
{
      "MMS07K5CCLT": {
        "doctor": "Dr. John M A",
        "doctor_id": "MMS07K5CCLT",
        "patients": {
          "MMXZV5F8A": {
            "appointment_end": 1652709621742,
            "appointment_start": 1652705121742,
            "arrived_at": 1652705098791,
            "dob": 712866600000,
            "gender": "male",
            "id": "MMXZV5F8A",
            "mail": "min@min.c",
            "mobile": "+919400490000",
            "name": "Minhaz MA",
            "status": "WAITING"
          }
        }
      }
}
```

Instead of the following patient object

```
{
            "appointment_end": 1652709621742,
            "appointment_start": 1652705121742,
            "arrived_at": 1652705098791,
            "dob": 712866600000,
            "gender": "male",
            "id": "MMXZV5F8A",
            "mail": "min@min.c",
            "mobile": "+919400490000",
            "name": "Minhaz MA",
            "status": "WAITING"
}
```

SUMMARY:

Structure - rtdb/"patients_today"/{$clinicId}/{$doctorId}/"patients"/{$patientId}/{patient-data}

Request - rtdb/"patients_today"/{$clinicId}/{$doctorId}/"patients"/{$patientId}

Returning - rtdb/"patients_today"/{$clinicId}

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Can you edit your question to show what is incorrect about the result you get back?

Answer (score 0):

use `var ref = await FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("patients_today/VN76Y0TNM/MMS07K5CCLT/patients/MMXZV5F8A").get();`

hope it will help you!

Comment: I tried it. It is giving me the same result.